# How can I have a different lock screen photo every time?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung

is it possible to always have the same lock screen photo and wallpaper, I want a different photo every time I open my phone. I got an app that can change my wallpaper but is it possible to make it change (or a different app) the lock screen also? My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a third party lock screen that uses the default wallpaper (this is androids default behaviour, but samsung have changed it), e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget&hl=en_GB 
(I think it uses default wallpaper)